Are Homework questions on-topic? If so, what standards do we want to set for them?
We have recently had a few questions that either outright indicated or strongly gave the impression of being homework. I do not think that it is our place to do students' homework for them. It is cheating, does not benefit the student, and leaves us with questions that are unlikely to be interesting to the general userbase of our site. However, if a question is asked in which the asker describes their approach and wishes to learn more about the background or needs guidance on how to think about the question at hand, there might be room to nudge them in the right direction.
Either way, I felt that we should perhaps have a discussion here to establish a policy how we want to deal with homework questions and what our expectations and standards for such questions are.

Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions, https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems
